How do I persist NextAuthV5/Authjs login error to the front end?
I'm re-creating my app from PHP to Next.js using Auth.js - trying to follow this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MTyCvS05V4&ab_channel=CodeWithAntonio
I am doing things a little differently (using mysql2 not Prisma) and I'm new to React/Next.js/Auth.js which is probably where I'm going wrong!
I can successfully log in, but I cannot get the specified errors to the front end if the credentials don't match.
These are the three files.
log-in-form.tsx
'use client'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import * as z from 'zod'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { LogInSchema } from '../../../../../../constants/validation-schemas'
import { logIn } from '../../../../../../actions/users/log-in'

export default function LogInForm() {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<z.infer<typeof LogInSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(LogInSchema),
    })

    async function onSubmit(credentials: z.infer<typeof LogInSchema>) {
        logIn(credentials)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div id="log-in-container">
                <form id="log-in-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <div className="label">
                        <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <input
                            {...register('username')}
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            maxLength={15}
                        />
                        {errors.username && (
                            <div className="error-message">
                                {errors.username.message}
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="label">
                        <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <input
                            {...register('password')}
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            maxLength={16}
                        />
                        {errors.password && (
                            <div className="error-message">
                                {errors.password.message}
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="log-in-button">
                        log in
                    </button>
                    {errors.root && (
                        <div className="error-message">
                            {errors.root.message}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { LogInSchema } from './constants/validation-schemas'
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs'
import { getPasswordByUsername } from './actions/users/get-password-by-username'
import { getUserIdByUsername } from './actions/users/get-user-id-by-username'
import { getSuspensionStatusByUsername } from './actions/users/get-suspension-status-by-username'

export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const validatedFields = LogInSchema.safeParse(credentials)

                if (validatedFields.success) {
                    const { username, password } = validatedFields.data

                    const user = await getUserIdByUsername(username)

                    if (!user) {
                        return null
                    }

                    const suspended = await getSuspensionStatusByUsername(
                        username
                    )

                    if (suspended) {
                        return null
                    }

                    const storedPassword = await getPasswordByUsername(username)

                    const passwordsMatch = await bcryptjs.compare(
                        password,
                        storedPassword
                    )

                    if (passwordsMatch) {
                        return await getUserIdByUsername(username)
                    }

                    return null
                }

                return null
            },
        }),
    ],
    session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user, token }) {
            return session
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
            return token
        },
    },
})

log-in.ts (server action)
'use server'
import * as z from 'zod'
import { LogInSchema } from '../../constants/validation-schemas'
import { signIn } from '../../auth'
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from '../../constants/routes'
import { AuthError } from 'next-auth'

export async function logIn(values: z.infer<typeof LogInSchema>) {
    const validatedFields = LogInSchema.safeParse(values)

    const { username, password } = validatedFields.data

    try {
        await signIn('credentials', {
            username,
            password,
            redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof AuthError) {
            switch (error.type) {
                case 'CredentialsSignin':
                    return { error: 'Invalid credentials.' }
                default:
                    return { error: 'Something went wrong.' }
            }
        }
        throw error
    }
}

I get an error logged in the terminal (CredentialsSignin) but I'm not sure how I persist the human readable error message to the front end.
Using next-auth 5.0.0-beta.25
Do I have to use react-hook-forms?
Thank you.
[auth][error] CredentialsSignin: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#credentialssignin
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:246:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:70:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:130:34)
    at async signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:53:17)
    at async logIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./actions/users/log-in.ts:23:9)

